# Calculate scale & position change based on pageYOffset

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following situation:

I have an object and its initial location;

When the page scroll starts, I need this object to start moving down and closer to the center, and when the scroll reaches 100vh ('sectionHeight' in the example below), I need it to be placed right in the center of the screen & be 1.49 bigger than the initial size.

I'm really struggling with maths here as I can't come up with a way of how to correctly calculate the way of the object, so far I just came up with the following code for the position change (but it's just random nums to try and match the final result) :

```
if(window.pageYOffset < sectionHeight && window.pageYOffset > 0) {
            productToExpand.style.position = 'absolute';
            productToExpand.style.top = productToExpandPosition.top + window.pageYOffset + 'px';
            productToExpand.style.left = productToExpandPosition.left + window.pageYOffset / 2 + 'px';
        } else if(window.pageYOffset === 0) {
            productToExpand.style.position = 'unset';
        }   else if (window.pageYOffset > sectionHeight) {
            productToExpand.style.top = 1.5 * sectionHeight - productImageToExpand.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
            productToExpand.style.left = 'calc(50% -' + ' ' + (productImageToExpand.offsetWidth / 2 + productToExpandPositionLeft) + 'px)';
        }
```

And I cannot really come up with the size change formula here. If anyone could help me on that, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood your query.  I have used bits and pieces of your code and added some.  I have put comments along with the code.

```
    var sectionHeight = vhToPixels(100); // section height in pixels
    var sectionWidth = vwToPixels(100); // section Width in pixels
   //console.log(sectionHeight + "  " + sectionWidth);
    
    var productToExpand = document.getElementById('image1');
    var productToExpandPosition;
    var imgHeight = productToExpand.clientHeight;
    var imgWidth = productToExpand.clientWidth;
    
    var multiplier;
    
    window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
    
    function myFunction() {
        //console.log(window.pageYOffset + " " + window.pageYOffset/2 + "  "  );
        if(window.pageYOffset < sectionHeight && window.pageYOffset > 0) {
            productToExpand.style.position = 'absolute';
            productToExpand.style.top =  window.pageYOffset + 'px';
            productToExpand.style.left =  window.pageYOffset / 2 + 'px';
            
            if((window.pageYOffset/500)  < 1) {
                multiplier = 1;
            }
            else {
                multiplier = (window.pageYOffset/500);
            }
            
            productToExpand.style.height = imgHeight * multiplier  + "px";
            productToExpand.style.width = imgWidth * multiplier + "px"; 
            
            
            //console.log(productToExpand.clientHeight + " " + productToExpand.clientWidth);
            console.log(window.pageYOffset/500);
            
        } else if(window.pageYOffset === 0) {
            productToExpand.style.position = 'unset';
            productToExpand.style.height = imgHeight  + "px";
            productToExpand.style.width = imgWidth  + "px";                
        }   else if (window.pageYOffset > sectionHeight) {
            //console.log("HERE");
            productToExpand.style.top = 1.5 * sectionHeight - productToExpand.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
            //console.log(productToExpand.style.top);
            productToExpand.style.left = sectionWidth + ' ' + (productToExpand.offsetWidth / 2 ) + 'px)';
            //console.log(productToExpand.style.left);
            productToExpand.style.height = imgHeight * 1.49 + "px";
            productToExpand.style.width = imgWidth * 1.49 + "px";
            
            console.log(productToExpand.clientHeight + " " + productToExpand.clientWidth);
        }            
        
    }
    
    function vhToPixels (vh) {
        //return Math.round(window.innerHeight / (100 / vh)) + 'px';
        return Math.round(window.innerHeight / (100 / vh));
    }
    function vwToPixels (vw) {
        //return Math.round(window.innerHeight / (100 / vh)) + 'px';
        return Math.round(window.innerWidth / (100 / vw));
    }
```

Comment: seems to be working ok, but in your code the size is not changing gradually, only when it reaches the innerHeight

Comment: Edited to make it gradual size increase.  The variable multiplier may need to be tweaked according to your requirements.